# Installing Scipy on centos 7 Digital Ocean

Tags: python, numpy, centos, scipy, digital-ocean

Running a small $5 developer server (Python3.5, Centos 7.1) with 512MB on Digital Ocean.
Installed NumPy and lapack lapack-devel blas blas-devel fine.
For pip install scipy I get the error below.

I can increase my droplet to 1 Gig but but prefer not to spend more than that. Any idea if 1 Gig would be enough (or if the installation issue is not related to memory at all..)

```
 In file included from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1781:0,
                     from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                     from scipy/sparse/sparsetools/sparsetools.h:5,
                     from scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.cxx:4:
    /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
      ^
    g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
    Please submit a full bug report,
    with preprocessed source if appropriate.
    See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.5 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4m6ciex2/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-uvjh2gng-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-4m6ciex2/scipy
```

Comment: Add swap to the machine?

Comment: I did, but that didn't help.

Comment: Does Digital Ocean let you shrink instances or launch images to a smaller instance? :-)

Comment: Yes they do but not easily if understand correctly...

Comment: Have you tried using yum to install a binary numpy/scipy?

Comment: Tnx! yum install scipy worked fine to install for my python 2.7 version, but not accessable from python 3.5. Normally I do pip3.5 install to send the package the right way. Tried to find info on how to do that with yum but fell short. I do not want to use virtualenv in this setup.